# yii2:align div horizontally in print?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I am using this simple code in my view.php. The div is aligned horizontally correctly, but it aligns vertically in print.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="col-lg-7" style="padding:5px;box-sizing: border-box;border: 1px solid #ddd;background-color:#f9f9f9">
            <b>Patient Name:</b> <?= $model->patient_name ?>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding:5px;box-sizing: border-box;border: 1px solid #ddd;background-color:#f9f9f9">
        <b> Auth. No.:</b> <?= $model->authorisation_number ?> 
    </div></div> </div>
```

I want these div to align horizontally in print as well. I am not using any custom print.css for this page.
[image: Div aligned horizontally]

Comment: You want this style: `display:inline`

Comment: Yes - where should I add it. should I create a separate print.css for this. when it is aligned in screen, should it not align same in print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer-

I need to use `<div class=col-xs-*>` in place of `<div class = col-lg-*>` that mostly achieves what I am looking for.

I welcome if there is any better workaround.

Thanks.